# Erro em obter dados em SQL

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Tenho este código:

```
SELECT Colaborador.IdColaborador, Colaborador.Numero, Colaborador.Nome, Colaborador.[Centro de Custo], Colaborador.Usuario,
Colaborador.Responsavel, Colaborador_1.Nome FROM Colaborador,
Colaborador AS Colaborador_1 WHERE
(((Colaborador_1.IdColaborador)=[Colaborador].[IdColaborador]));
```

Onde quero obter o nome do responsável que também é um Colaborador mas o resultado é o nome do Colaborador repetido 2 vezes.

O que estou a fazer mal ?

Comment: Qual é o erro que você recebe?

Comment: eu recebo o nome do primeiro colaborador sempre, não recebo o seu responsável.

Comment: Você não tem um IdResponsavel?

Comment: Responsavel é o IdResponsavel, que tambem é IdColaborador

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certamente você não esta fazendo o relacionamento correto.

Veja no seu Where você faz:

```
(((Colaborador_1.IdColaborador)=[Colaborador].[IdColaborador]))
```

Isso vai fazer um JOIN com os mesmo dados do seu colaborado, o que você precisar e verificar o Id do Responsável para fazer a relação.

```
  SELECT Colaborador.IdColaborador, Colaborador.Numero, Colaborador.Nome, Colaborador.[Centro de Custo], Colaborador.Usuario,
Colaborador.Responsavel, Colaborador_1.Nome FROM Colaborador,
Colaborador AS Colaborador_1 WHERE
(((Colaborador_1.IdColaborador)=[Colaborador].[IdResponsavel]));
```

Comment: Isto é para usar no Access e dá o seguinte erro: Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: Ok, mas certamente você tem em sua tabela um Id do responsável, então no seu select você tem que trocar o  a sua relação por esse id tipo `(((Colaborador_1.IdColaborador)=[Colaborador].[IdResponsavel]));`

Comment: Alterei a resposta, o que você tem que entender é que os dados do primeiro Colaborador são os dados principais e neles contém a chave secundaria FK que é o  IdResponsavel você tem que usar esse id na sua relação.